# Obtener ruta de un archivo selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buena noche estoy usando un ```  para obtener la ruta de un archivo que seleciona el usuario exactamente un excel para extraer unos datos pero al seleccionarlo y enviarlo la ruta que recibo es la siguiente -->  C:\fakepath\Cargamasiva2.xls <-- y pues esta incompleta como puedo obtener la ruta con JQuery o con Js ??

```js
function cargar() {
  ruta = document.getElementById('ruta').value;
  console.log(ruta);
    
  // $.post("users?menu=Consultar&accion=Carga", {ruta: ruta});
}
```

```html
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
<button id="bntcarga" type="button"  value="Carga" class="btn btn-success" onclick="cargar();">Probar</button>
<input  name="ruta" id="ruta" type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
```

Comment: Con js o jquery no se tiene acceso a la rutas reales del usuario. Sería un problema de seguridad grave.

Comment: La preguntas son, ¿por que necesitas la ruta real del archivo local y con JQuery?. ¿Estas trabajando con electron para una app que utilice el dom u otro framework de node? ¿o solo en web?. Tal vez si ofreces un poco mas de contexto se pueda llegar a una solución, saludos.

Comment: Hola @DєηyηCrawford , disculpame pues mira estoy realizando cargas masivas a una base de datos de un excel, estoy trabajando con java jsp, en mi codigo me lee es la ruta del archivo aquel que el usuario seleciona cuando oprime el boton examinar que abre la ventana de windows para buscar un archivo, para eso necesito obtener la ruta o nose que otra opcion exista mejor para realizar eso. JQuery o Js me envian la ruta al controlador y de hay la paso a la logica donde realiza la carga masiva con esos datos del excel.

Comment: Pero la pero mis dudas aún son las mismas , ¿que tiene que ver el front end con tus procesos internos? ¿Para que necesitas ese dato del lado del cliente? ¿Qué va a hacer el cliente con ella? ¿O a caso quieres abrir la ruta desde el navegador?

Comment: Para ir al punto, ¿Cuál es el objetivo final de obtener la ruta?

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford es para leer un excel y hacer una carga masiva con esos datos a mysql usando java

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas la ruta, necesitas un objeto `File` para poder leer el archivo en alguno de estos formatos:

- base64
- ArrayBuffer
- text

Si lo que necesitas es leer estos datos en alguno de estos 3 formatos para enviarlos a java, para realizar nuestro cometido javascript provee un objeto llamado `FileReader` el cuál es importante saber que por cada archivo que vayas a leer debes crear una nueva instancia de este y asignarle los respectivos eventos de carga necesarios, de lo contrario es muy normal que te salte una excepción parecida a:

**Exception: FileReader is busy.**

O algo parecido, no recuerdo como es exactamente la excepción pero lo que se es que alguna vez me salto esa excepción, bien, dicho esto, aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso de `FileReader`:

```js
function readAsBase64(fileBlob){

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {

        const fileReader = new FileReader;
            
        fileReader.onload = ev =>{
            res(ev.target.result);
        };

        fileReader.onerror = e => {
            rej(e);
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);

    });

}

function handleFiles(ev){
    
    //Devuelve un objeto llamado FileList no instanciable
    const files = ev.currentTarget.files;
    
    //Leamos por ejemplo solo el primer archivo:
    readAsBase64(files[0]).then(fileInBase64 =>{
       console.log(fileInBase64);
    }).catch(e =>{
       console.error(e);
    })
}
```

```html
<input type = "file" id = "fileInput" accept = "image/*" onchange = "handleFiles(event)">
```

Esto es para el caso de que quieras leer el archivo usando el formato `base64` el cual es bastante seguro para entrega de información sin perdida y sin posibilidad de corrupción mientras se enviá al otro lado, sin embargo es un poco mas pesado que otros formatos.

Los 4 metodos de lectura que tiene `FileReader` son:

- readAsDataURL (seguro pero un poco mas pesado)
- readAsArrayBuffer (no tan seguro pero ligero)
- readAsText (no seguro y semipesado)
- readAsBinaryString (nunca lo uses, se considera inseguro y deprecado)

Yo te recomiendo usar el formato base64 para enviar los datos, luego quitarle el formato:

```
data:mime-type que te devuelva fileReader;base64,  //NO OLVIDES LA COMA QUE HAY AL FINAL
```

del lado de java, ojo, solo cuando los datos ya hayan sidos enviados a java, ya que de lo contrario a la hora de leer los datos seguro habra un error, esto: `data:mime-type que te devuelva fileReader;base64,` en su mayor parte solo es una información extra que normalmente solo se interpreta por el navegador para que él sepa de que manera interpretar los datos e incluso si se deben ejecutar.

Pero del lado de java 100% debes quitar esa parte, quedandote con un trozo parecido a esto:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAQCAwMDAgQDAwMEBAQEBQkGBQUFBQsICAYJDQsNDQ0LDAwOEBQRDg8TDwwMEhgSExUWFxcXDhEZG
```

etc... una vez hecho eso, deberas decodificar el archivo que esta en base64, en jsp y guardarlo en alguna variable para posteriormente usar esta información como desees, debe haber una función que te permita hacerlo, o siempre también puedes enviarlo por ArrayBuffer, que java creo que lo puede leer de manera directa y no tienes que hacer este proceso.

Tambien creo que es buena idea explicar un poco que es una `Promise`, ya que la estoy usando...

Una promise es un objeto que nos proveee de 2 `callbacks`, uno en caso de que nuestra operación finalice con exito y otra en caso de que ocurra un error, en ambos casos una promise debe ya sea resolverse o rechazarse, y la manera de hacerle saber a una promise cuando se ha cumplido un proceso con exito o no, es invocando a los callbacks que nos provee, el primer callback es el que se invoca cuando todo ha ido bien, es decir nuestra promise fue resuelta con exito, el segundo callback es exactamente lo contrario, ademas a estas funciones al invocarlas podemos pasarle un parametro a manera de `return statement`:

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {

    //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se resuelve
    res('podemos retornar algo aquí tambien');

    //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se rechaza, y retornamos algo
    rej('retornando algo, un error por ejemplo');

});
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que estos dos callbacks proveidos por nuestra `Promise` una vez se ejecutan es como si hicieramos `return` es decir, lo que este debajo ya no se ejecutara, tambien decir que una promise puede tener 3 estados:

- Pending
- Resolved
- Rejected

Donde el primero siempre será el inicial, ademas una promise solamente puede ser resuelta o rechazada una vez, y `una vez este resuelta o rechazada no puede cambiar de estado de nuevo`.

Las promises se inventaron a manera de evitar algo llamado **callback hell** lo cuál se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes de existir las promesas, debiamos esperar a que una función que posiblemente se demorase un tiempo en ser terminada o ejecutada, ejecutaramos otra que posiblemente tambien se demorase bastante, bien algo como eso puede evitarse con simplemente 3 o 4 lineas ahora:

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

De manera que el objetivo de una promise es poder manejar código asíncrono de manera mas estructurada, código el cuál puede demorarse un rato en terminar de ejecutarse, como por ejemplo leer un archivo muy largo, el cuál puede ser tu caso.

Ademas una ultima cosa que me gustaría exponer sobre las promises son sus metodos `then` y `catch`, a manera de resumen, then se ejecuta cuando la promesa ha sido resuelta con exito y nos trae el valor ya procesado en el tiempo.

catch nos trae un error o la información que le hayamos pasado en caso de que la promesa haya sido rechazada.

entonces tenemos:

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {

    //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se resuelve
    res('podemos retornar algo aquí tambien');

    //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se rechaza, y retornamos algo
    rej('retornando algo, un error por ejemplo');

}).then(response =>{
   //Solamente aquí dentro tendras disponible tu información
}).catch(error =>{
   //Solamente aquí dentro tendras disponible tu error
})
```

Recuerda que una promise no es una función normal, si tratas de acceder al valor de una promise sin antes esta haberse resuelto o rechazado el valor que te arrojara siempre sera undefined:

```js
let resultadoPromise;

const miPromesa = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            
    setTimeout(()=>{
        //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se resuelve
        res('podemos retornar algo aquí tambien');

        //Si lo ejecutamos la promesa se rechaza, y retornamos algo
        rej('retornando algo, un error por ejemplo');
    }, 5000)

}).then(response =>{
   //Solamente aquí dentro tendras disponible tu información
   resultadoPromise = response;
   //Verás esto despues de 5 segundos.
   console.log(resultadoPromise);
}).catch(error =>{
   //Solamente aquí dentro tendras disponible tu error
});

/*
  La promesa aún no se completaba, por lo cuál aún no llegaba a then(),
  y como a resultadoPromise aún no se le ha asignado ningun valor el resultado es
  undefined.
*/
console.log(resultadoPromise);
```

Espero te haya sido de utilidad mi respuesta, alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Cabe destacar también que en caso de que estes por ejemplo usando PHP como intermediario para poder subir esta información a tu base de datos, entonces lo mejor es NO usar FileReader, lo mejor es simplemente postear directamente. y usar la variable $_FILES que provee PHP, que es la que guarda los archivos subidos por ti, sin embargo si jsp no soporta que se le envien directamente los objetos File para hacer escritura con ellos luego por ejemplo, entonces deberas usar esta opción.

Comment: Bueno... creo que acabo de encontrar un ejemplo que permite obtener varios archivos en jsp solamente posteandolos... no uses entonces mi solución no es buena debido a que jsp si permite usar los File directamente checa este articulo: https://ingeniods.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/subir-archivos-en-jsp/ aunque creo que no borrare mi respuesta puede ser util para otras cosas :'3