# Array vacío al enviarlo en llamada API ejecutada después de una Promesa

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Por qué `photosToSend` llega vacío a mi base de datos después de enviarse por `axios.patch` en el siguiente código? En la función la promesa rellena un array (photosToSend) con strings (`urls.location`). He comprobado con console.log que efectivamente el array es rellenado con strings. No sólo eso sino que aunque en el código no aparezca también he hecho console.log abajo donde `axios.patch` y también está relleno. Sin embargo a mi base de datos llega vacio.

```js
uploadPhoto(e){
   
    const photosToSend = []
    new Promise(function() {
        
        for(let i= 0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
            ReactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[i], s3configUpload)
            .then((urls) => {
                console.log(urls.location)
                photosToSend.push(urls.location)
            })
            .catch((err) => {alert(err)})
        }
        console.log(photosToSend)
      }).then(
        axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
            site: this.props.match.params.gallery_name + "_" + this.state.authenticatedUser,
            // Pero aquí se envía vacío
            photos: photosToSend
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
       
      )
    
}
```

Así aparece en console.log:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo me extraña que sea problema de la API, porque si hago manualmente lo que supuestamente debería ser la estructura de `photosToSend` si que funciona:

```js
.then(() => {
            axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
                site: this.props.match.params.gallery_name + "_" + this.state.authenticatedUser,
               
                photos: [
                    "urldeprueba.com",
                    "urldeprueba2.com
                ]
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
           }
          )
```

Cúal puede ser el problema entonces?

Comment: Efectivamente Javier, los objetos en Javascript son `clave: valor`, lo que puedes hacer es en vez un objeto, mandar un array, no? El array si te permite tener una lista de strings

Comment: Si, me acabo de dar cuenta, fue un error tonto. Lo extraño es que lo acabo de hacer y sigue enviándose vacío. Voy actualizar el OP, a ver si puedes ver algo que se me haya escapado.

Comment: no sé si es un error al ponerlo aqui el código pero el .then que tienes despues del bucle for, debería ser `.then(() => ...)` Y otra cosa, `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })` o `Promise.resolve().then(() => { ... })`

Comment: Ok, gracias. Pues lo he puesto así y sigue llegando vacío. Si hago console.log dentro del then(), el array está completo. Pero sin embargo en la API se manda vacío al parecer. Y si lo mando así photos: {
                        photosToSend
                    } También llega vacío.

Comment: Puedes comprobar en el navegador, en la pestaña Network de chrome por ejemplo el payload de la request? Esta saliendo correctamente?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar a usar Promise.all para retornar el resultado de muchas promesas. Quedaria algo asi

```
uploadPhoto(e){
   const getUrls = () => {
        let arrayphotos = [];
        for(let i= 0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
            let p = ReactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[i], s3configUpload)
            .then(urls => {
                return urls.location;
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err));

            arrayphotos.push(p);
        }

        return Promise.all(arrayphotos);
   };

   const allUrls = getUrls();

   axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
      site: this.state.site,
      photos: allUrls
   }).then(() => {
      console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
   }).catch(err => console.log(err))    
 };
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha enviado igual un objeto vacío. Pero creo que ya se porque puede ser y es que allUrls queda tal que asi: 0:"urldeprueaba.com, 1:"urldeprueba.com". Es decir parece que la estructura no sirve para mandar por Json, y la promesa no era el problema.

Comment: le cambio el titulo porque el problema al parecer era distinto pero gracias por tu aportación

Answer (score 1):

No uso axios pero lo use alguna vez, y nunca he usado react, pero algun día lo hare, sin embargo me preocupa esta linea:

```
.then(
    axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
        site: this.props.match.params.gallery_name + "_" + this.state.authenticatedUser,
        // Pero aquí se envía vacío
        photos: photosToSend
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

)
```

Me preocupa entonces:

- then recibe un callback, pero le estas pasando la ejecución entera de `axios.patch` la cuál tardara un rato en ejecutarse y por lo tanto fallará.

Que tal si intentas arreglar el problema colocando todo dentro de un callback en el then?

```
.then(()=>{

    axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
        site: this.props.match.params.gallery_name + "_" + this.state.authenticatedUser,
        // Pero aquí se envía vacío
        photos: photosToSend
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

})
```

No se si esto vaya a ayudar a que se resuelva el problema, pero como no conozco mucho de axios ni de react, es algo que se me ocurre del por que puede estar fallando.

Bueno tambien otra cosa que me preocupa es que la Promise siempre obtiene como parametros dos callbacks, el primer fallo es que tu promise esta vaciá:

```
//Mal
new Promise(function() {

}

//Bien
new Promise((res, rej) =>{

   //Tu código aquí dentro.

});
```

Lo otro es que nunca le estas diciendo a la promise que se resuelva o se rechaze, es decir nunca usas los callbacks res y rej, que se le pasan a la promise, ademas recuerda que un ciclo `for` es sincrono y nunca va a esperar a que tus promesas se resuelvan o se rechazen, mira entonces lo siguiente:

```
function uploadFile(file, s3configUpload){

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {

        ReactS3.uploadFile(file, s3configUpload)
        .then((urls) => {
            console.log(urls.location)
            photosToSend.push(urls.location)
            res(photosToSend);
        })
        .catch((err) => {alert(err); rej(err)})

    })

}

//De aquí para abajo todo esto tiene que estar donde lo tenias en el código original.
new Promise(async (res, rej) =>{

    for(let i= 0; i<e.target.files.length; i++){
        await uploadFile(e.target.files[i], s3configUpload);
    }

    console.log(photosToSend)
    res(photosToSend);

}).then((photosToSend)=>{

    axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-pictures`, {
        site: this.props.match.params.gallery_name + "_" + this.state.authenticatedUser,
        // Pero aquí se envía vacío
        photos: photosToSend
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('DB-Galleries en Dynamo updated')
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))

}).catch(e =>{
    console.error(e);
})
```

Se ha dividido el código en 2 entonces, una función especialmente dedicada a subir archivos llamada `uploadFile` ademas se usan los callbacks `res` y `rej` de la promise que tu anteriormente nunca habias pasado y por lo tanto tampoco usado.

Por ultimo hacemos de la funcion de la promise, una función asincrona:

```
new Promise(async (res, rej) =>{

})
```

**Si no la hacemos asincrona no vamos a poder usar await dentro de ella**, el await tiene como objetivo obligar al ciclo for a esperar a que la promesa sea resuelta o rechazada para seguir iterando, de esta manera, cuando todos los archivos finalicen su carga en el servidor, se resolvera la promise:

```
new Promise(async (res, rej) =>{

   //Ciclo for, y carga de archivos...


   //Se llega aquí cuando ya se paso por el for
   //Se resuelve la promesa
   res(photosToSend);
})
```

Como digo, no se si esto vaya a funcionar pero allí le hago unas correciones a las promises.

Comment: Por cierto, te remito a este link mio, donde respondí una pregunta acerca de subir archivos, sin embargo no mires la parte de subir archivos si la consultas, mira mas bien la parte donde estan lo de las promises, posiblemente te interese: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346815/obtener-ruta-de-un-archivo-selecionado/347091#347091