# Cuando utilizar promise y cuando un método

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Hola estoy comenzando en javascript, mongo y nodejs, pero tengo una confusión tengo métodos que involucran query a BD y las tengo como promesas, sin embrago hay procesos que hago una vez tomado ese resultado y honestamente no se cuando hacerlo a través de una promesa o a través de una función convencional.

aqui un codigo con una promesa:

```
  async function comparacionTotalProceso(litsaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


                var result = litsaTotal.map(elem => (listaFiltrada.some(elem2 => 

                    elem.user_id === elem2.previo.cliente_id ) ? { ...elem } :  null        
                    ))


            return resolve(result);
        })

    }
```

pero tambien puedo realizarlo sin la promesa:

```
async function comparacionTotalProceso(litsaTotal, listaFiltrada) {



                var result = litsaTotal.map(elem => (listaFiltrada.some(elem2 => 

                    elem.user_id === elem2.previo.cliente_id ) ? { ...elem } :  null        
                    ))


            return(result;
        })

    }
```

y trae el mismo resultado tanto con la promise y sin ella, en esta consulta me ayudo el amigo Riven por el cual estoy en deuda con el.

disculpen mi ignorancia estoy comenzando.

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo donde muestre como utilizas las promesas y las funciones convencionales?

Comment: Una promise no es una función, es una clase, utilizar una función no es lo mismo que usar la instancia de una promise.

Comment: Riven @DavidMinaya14 gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cuanto a cuando usar una `promise`, dependerá de si lo que estas realizando es `asincrono` o de si es una operación que vaya a tardar un tiempo (de hecho este es el concepto en el que mas se usan las `promises`), de lo contrario si no es una operación que vaya a demorar y no sea `asincrona`, conviene siempre usar funciones de manera común y corriente, puesto que las funciones normales en javascript **son sincronas**, a menos que le especifiquemos estrictamente desde js que se comporten como `asincronas`.

Ahora bien, no te culpo por esto, pero creo que ambos en algún punto nos confundimos con las `promises` y las funciones `asincronas` ya que pensabamos por ejemplo... ¿De qué sirve tener una promise si puedo usar una función asincrona?, o alrevez, ¿De qué sirve tener una función asincrona si puedo usar una promise?

Bien, estas respuestas se resumen a lo siguiente.

Si retornas una `promise` dentro de una `función sincrona` la función seguirá siendo sincrona sin embargo **la naturaleza de una promise siempre es asincrona y no puede ser cambiada.**

En resumen cuando retornas una `promise` dentro de una función sincrona no estas haciendo que la promise sea sincrona ni que la función sincrona se torne en asincrona, si no que simplemente estamos creando un 'manejador' de la asincroneidad dentro de nuestra función, para poder obtener luego los valores de nuestra promise en cualquier parte luego, (nos da un mejor control de tanto errores como de los posibles datos traidos por la promise).

Ahora bien, si en vez de usar una `promise`, decides usar una `función asincrona`, debes tener en cuenta y muy muy importante:

**Una funcion asincrona siempre, siempre, siempre retorna una promise**

No hay ningún caso en el que una función asíncrona no retorne una `promise`, ya que aunque no le especifiquemos que se retorne un valor (que no haya sentencia return), una función asincrona siempre te va a devolver una promise cuando es ejecutada.

Esto te puede sonar a algo similar que simplemente tener nuestra `función sincrona` y dentro de esta retornar una `promise`, es decir podemos verlo como si 'hicieramos asincrona una función sincrona', pero esto es incorrecto, ya que una función sincrona siempre será sincrona, pero **una función asincrona puede comportarse como sincrona**, por ejemplo si usamos `await` dentro de una función asincrona hacemos que se pause la ejecución de nuestro código hasta que la `promise` se resuelva o se rechace.

Para clarificar un poco:

- **Función sincrona:** no puede comportarse como asincrona nunca.
- **Función asincrona:** puede comportarse de las dos formas si se lo especificamos.

Entonces ya que entendimos estas ideas, vamos a ver primero la primera parte que tienes de tu código, que es esta de acá:

```
async function comparacionTotalProceso(litsaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        var result = litsaTotal.map(elem => (listaFiltrada.some(elem2 => 

             elem.user_id === elem2.previo.cliente_id ) ? { ...elem } :  null        
        ))

        return resolve(result);
     })

}
```

Esto claro que funcionaria bien, pero es redundante, es decir, recordemos que una función asíncrona siempre retornara si o si, una promise y ahí mismo lo que estas haciendo es retornando **una promise dentro de otra promise**.

La primera promise es la que siempre retornara nuestra función asincrona, mientras que la segunda es aquella que estas retornando como valor a la promise de la función asincrona, lo cuál realmente no tiene mucho sentido si se trata de una función asincrona... para que tenga sentido esa función no debería ser asincrona:

```
function comparacionTotalProceso(litsaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        var result = litsaTotal.map(elem => (listaFiltrada.some(elem2 => 

             elem.user_id === elem2.previo.cliente_id ) ? { ...elem } :  null        
        ))

        /*
          No necesitas retornar resolve()... puedes solo llamar a resolve()
          y hará el mismo efecto que el return.
        */
        return resolve(result);
     })

}
```

Aquí ya estaríamos retornando correctamente una sola `promise`.

En la segunda parte de tu código:

```
async function comparacionTotalProceso(litsaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

    var result = litsaTotal.map(elem => (listaFiltrada.some(elem2 => 

        elem.user_id === elem2.previo.cliente_id ) ? { ...elem } :  null        
        ))

    //Tenias un error aquí
    return result;

}
```

Estas retornando directamente un valor, este será el valor de la `promise` resuelta, es decir, como nuestra función es asincrona el valor de `<fullfilled>` de la promise será aquello que hayas retornado en la función asincrona, y en caso de que ocurra un error, no habrá un state `<fullfilled>` en la `promise` si no que en este caso será el state `<rejected>` que guardara nuestro error, esto es automático en las funciones asíncronas y una diferencia que hay entre las funciones sincronas que usan promises y las funciones asincronas (también usan promises pero la forma de resolver o rechazar cosas es distinta).

Ahora bien, si quieres evitar por ejemplo un `UnhandledPromiseRejectionError` dentro de una función `asincrona`, puedes usar bloques `try - catch` para una operación que sea riesgosa y que de vez en cuando pueda haber errores, como por ejemplo operaciones de leer o escribir información.

Bien entonces ya sabemos que tanto el ejemplo de arriba como el de abajo retornan promises, solo que el primero es redundate.

**Habría entonces que preguntarse cuando utilizar una promise y cuando un metodo aún??**

Realmente sí, puesto que hay que aclarar algunas cosas, primero definamos unas cuantas cosas:

**- Metodo:** Código reusable dinamico que se encuentra y hace parte de una clase.

**- Función:** Código reusable definido explicitamente como `function` y que **no hace parte de una clase** (si la function estuviese en una clase ya no sería llamado función, sería llamado metodo).

**- Promise:** Clase instanciable la cuál su instancia es de naturaleza asincrona y que permite manejar de mejor forma código asíncrono u operaciones que vayan a tardar un tiempo en realizarse.

Ahora bien habiendo definido esto entonces la pregunta ya no sería mas:

**Habría entonces que preguntarse cuando utilizar una promise y cuando un metodo aún??**

Si no mas bien:

**Habría entonces que preguntarse cuando utilizar una promise y cuando una función aún??**

puesto que en los ejemplos de código tuyos no se evidencía `metodos` si no funciones.

Sin embargo si, aún habría que preguntarse cuando utilizar una promise y cuando una función o método (depende de donde se encuentre o haga parte).

Voy a responder esta pregunta teniendo en cuenta mi experiencia con las promises:

**Usa promises cuando te encuentres con operaciones asincronas u operaciones que vayan a tardar un tiempo y que tengas que manejar tambien en otras partes del código**

Por ejemplo, pongamos de ejemplo a `ajax`, `ajax` no usa promises nativamente por lo que no te va a dar una promise, pero sin embargo es de naturaleza asincrona.

Esto quiere decir que estamos limitados a solo poder usar nuestros datos cuando ajax los haya cargado, y cuando los cargue solo los podremos usar en una función en especial de ajax que te da esta información una vez ajax la haya cargado.

vamos a ver en pseudocódigo lo que digo (notese que en ambos pseudocódigos la función HacerPeticionAjax es sincrona (no se declara como async)):

```
HacerPeticionAjax:

   unaVezCargadoHacer:
      //Solo aquí se puede usar datos traidos por ajax al no usar promises.
      imprimir informacionAjax;
      retornar informacionAjax;
   fin unaVezCargadoHacer;

finHacerPeticionAjax;

//Datos no disponibles acá afuera (aún no cargados).
variable datos = HacerPeticionAjax();
```

Ahora pongamos un ejemplo con el mismo pseudocódigo pero esta vez usando una promise:

```
HacerPeticionAjax:

    retornarNuevaPromesa:

        unaVezCargadoHacer:
            imprimir informacionAjax;
            resolver informacionAjax;
        fin unaVezCargadoHacer;

        enCasoDeErrorHacer:
            rechazar error;

finHacerPeticionAjax;

HacerPeticionAjax()
    entonces datos:
        //Datos disponibles fuera de HacerPeticionAjax
        imprimir datos;

    capturar error:
        imprimir error;
```

Como vemos las promises nos proveen un mejor control hacía donde y como queremos usar nuestros datos y ademas nos permiten controlar de mejor forma el flujo asincrono.

Otro ejemplo es por ejemplo si quisiéramos cargar una imagen de manera controlada, o algún archivo, entonces convendría usar promises en conjunto con funciones sincronas.

Y que pasa entonces con las funciones o metodos? cuando deberíamos usarlos?

Para el caso de las funciones sincronas, se deben o deberían usar cuando por ejemplo queremos que algo tenga un orden de ejecución concreto, un flujo en este caso de derecha a izquierda y de arriba a abajo (así se comporta el flujo sincrono), con la imposibilidad de ejecutar varias cosas al mismo tiempo.

Para el caso de las funciones asincronas, su mejor uso y su uso mas frecuente es cuando queremos que código que sea asincrono que este dentro de nuestra función asincrona (por ejemplo una llamada a ajax se comporte como si fuera código sincrono), es decir, esperar a nuestra respuesta de ajax para obtener datos (se puede usar la sentencia await para esto).

Voy hacer un ejemplo en javascript de esto:

Código asincrono sin usar await intentando que se comporte como sincrono, que fallara o no hará lo que esperas al ser asincrono:

```js
let datos = undefined;

async function setDatos(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    datos = 10;
  }, 2000)
}

setDatos();
console.log(datos);
```

Como vemos nos devuelve `undefined`, puesto que nuestra función es `asincrona` y javascript es `sincrono`, por lo que `JS` no se va a detener a esperar a que nuestra función haga sus cosas, simplemente deja que la función se ejecute y mientras que eso pasa hace sus demás cosas.

Ahora bien, hagamos el mismo ejemplo pero esta vez haciendo uso de la sentencia `await`, que ojo, **solo se puede hacer uso de esta sentencia dentro de funciones asincronas**, ademas no puede ser usada en el contexto global.

```js
window.onload = async()=>{

  let datos = undefined;

  async function setDatos(){
    return await new Promise((res, rej) =>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        datos = 10;
        res();
      }, 2000)
    });
  }

  await setDatos();
  console.log(datos);

}
```

Se tuvo que hacer una modificación puesto que `await` no puede ser usado en el contexto global, así que todo el código fue encerrado en otra funcion que es asincrona, pero como vemos, tenemos una función asincrona dentro de otra pero el código ahora se comporta como sincrono debido al `await`.

**Conclusiónes:**

- Siempre que no tengamos código asincrono o hagamos tareas que puedan tardar un tiempo es mejor no usar `promises` ni `funciones asincronas`.
- Es mejor usar promises en una función sincrona si queremos tener mejor control de código que vaya ser asincrono o que sea pensado para hacerse asincrono.
- Es mejor usar funciones asincronas si queremos que alguna llamada que vaya tardar un tiempo en ejecutarse se comporte de manera sincrona en un contexto asincrono.
- Una `función asincrona` siempre retorna una `promise` dentro de ella, ya sea que le especifiquemos un valor de retorno a la función o no, por lo que debemos o deberíamos olvidarnos de retornar promises dentro de una función asincrona ya que como tal esta ya retorna una promise, solo tenemos que encargarnos de retornar aquel valor que deseamos que tenga nuestra función asincrona, y salvo en ciertos casos excepcionales que requieras retornar una promise dentro de una función asincrona, es mejor no hacerlo puesto que si quieres el valor en bruto en una sola promise podras lograrlo usando `await` dentro.

Comment: Si quieres mas info sobre las promises te remito a una pregunta que respondí que no tenia que ver del todo con promises, pero termine explicandolas un poco mas a fondo y en funcionamiento, aquí te comparto mi respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346815/obtener-ruta-de-un-archivo-selecionado

Comment: muchisimas gracias, clase magistral, se notan tus conocimientos y tu nobleza de poderlos compartir, muy agradecido honestamente por tu tiempo y por ser, gracias y bendiciones